# Why is this throwing an exception when I try to save the attachment from Outlook?

Tags: python, outlook, email-attachments, win32com, office-automation

I am trying to iterate through the contents of a subfolder, and if the message contains an .xlsx attachment, download the attachment to a local directory. I have confirmed all other parts of this program work until that line, which throws an exception each time.

I am running the following code in a Jupyter notebook through VSCode:

```
# import libraries
import win32com.client
import re
import os

# set up connection to outlook

path = os.path.expanduser("~\\Desktop\\SBD_DB")
print(path)

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
target_folder = inbox.Folders['SBD - Productivity'].Folders['Productivity Data Request']
target_folder.Name

messages = target_folder.Items
message = messages.GetLast()

# while True:
x=0
while x < 100:
  try:
    # print(message.subject) # get the subject of the email
    for attachment in message.attachments:
        if 'xlsx' in attachment.FileName: 
            # print("reached")
            attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(path, str(attachment.FileName)))
            print("found excel:", attachment.FileName)
    message = messages.GetPrevious()
    x+=1
  except:
    print("exception")
    message = messages.GetPrevious()
    x+=1
```

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: @takendarkk I don't know, I am not getting any error code, it just executes the "except" part of the "try-except" block and then continues to the next iteration. If I remove the attachment.SaveAsFile line, it executes the "try" portion every time with no exceptions.

Comment: Your except block is throwing away the exception for some reason. You should get it and log it.

Comment: @takendarkk nice, I did not know about logger.

ERROR:root:message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bdibuz01\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_23704\3137415355.py", line 28, in <cell line: 22>
    attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(path, str(attachment.FileName)))
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 2, in SaveAsFile
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'Cannot save the attachment. Path does not exist. Verify the path is correct.', None, 0, -2147024893), None)
ERROR:root:message

Comment: Are you sure the target folder exists on the disk? Did you try to create the folder before calling the SaveAsFile method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the following line of code throws an exception at runtime:

```
attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(path, str(attachment.FileName)))
```

First, make sure that you deal with an attached file, not a link to the actual file. The [Attachment.Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.type) property returns an `OlAttachmentType` constant indicating the type of the specified object. You are interested in the `olByValue` value when the attachment is a copy of the original file and can be accessed even if the original file is removed.

Second, you need to make sure that the file path (especially the `FileName` property) doesn't contain forbidden symbols, see [What characters are forbidden in Windows and Linux directory names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names) for more information.

Third, make sure that a target folder exists on the disk and points to the local folder. According to the exception message:

```
 'Cannot save the attachment. Path does not exist. Verify the path is correct.'
```

That is it. Try to open the folder manually first, according to the error message the path doesn't exist. Before calling the `SaveAsFile` method you need to created the target folder or make sure it exists before.

Comment: Bingo - I assumed it would create & move into the directory when the path was specified, but I had to manually create the folder first. Thanks.